# determine target resolution of Class reference in a Rails file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am reviewing an older code base and have happened upon a reference to a Class whose source I can't identify.  Is there a way to determine what it resolves to easily? Ideally this would be with a command line utility rather than running the code with changes to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the class has methods defined, you can use [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) (the awesome IRB alternative) to get the source code for the class, which also tells you the path to the file where it's defined.

```
[1] pry(main)> ClassName  # First make sure the class is loaded
[2] pry(main)> show-source ClassName
```

Comment: Going to give this a try when I get a minute to check out pry

Answer (score 0):

Recursive grep usually works well for me.  Try something like this from the top directory of your Rails project:

```
grep -r ClassName .
```

Grep is case-sensitive by default.